# How to calculate Matrix efficiently in C++?

Tags: c++

I am new to C++ and programming so I think I am making inefficient codes.

I was wondering whether there is any way I can speed up the matrix calculation process.

For example, this is the sample code I write which finds the maximum differences(in absolute value) between 3d array 'V' and 'Vnew'.

First, I take subtraction.
And then, I put the value of tempdiff[0][0][0] to 'dif'

Then, I compare 'dif' and tempdiff[i][j][k] and replace if the latter is larger than the former.

This is just a part of my code and there are lots of matrix calculations inside so that I have too many 'for' statements.

So I was wondering whether there is any way I could avoid using 'for' in the matrix calculations.

Thanks in advance.

```
       for (int i = 0; i < Na; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < Nd; j++) {
                for (int k = 0; k < Ny; k++) {
                    tempdiff[i][j][k] = abs(V[i][j][k] - Vnew[i][j][k]);
                }
            }
        }

        dif = tempdiff[0][0][0];

        for (int i = 0; i < Na; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < Nd; j++) {
                for (int k = 0; k < Ny; k++) {
                    if (tempdiff[i][j][k] > dif) {
                        dif = tempdiff[i][j][k];
                    }
                    else {
                        dif = dif;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: 1. use 1-D array  2. use ternary operator  3. do two works in a single loop, not single work in two loops

Comment: Define "efficiently". If you need absolute performance then you need to give up on this approach and find a pre-existing library that's already tuned and tested. There are *many* to pick from. These often employ CPU-specific tricks using SIMD instructions do to this more efficiently. One that can leverage GPU compute, if that's an option, will often be *several orders of magnitude* faster than your CPU can ever muster.

Comment: Ternary operator is absolutely not a magic bullet to optimization. Compilers really know it's a short hand for `if, then,else` and can generate exactly the same code from both expressions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's not much you can do with the for loops, as the maximum difference can locate at all possible places. **You have already succeeded in iterating the array in the correct, linear, order.**

Compilers are generally quite efficient in optimising, but they apparently fail to flatten a contiguous array, such as `float V[Na][Nd][Ny];`. After you flatten it manually to `float V[Na*Nd*Ny]`, at least clang can auto-vectorise and produce SIMD code for x64 and arm.

A further optimisation is to avoid making this in two steps, as the total memory throughput is exactly doubled with the temporary array compared to a one-pass solution.

I was assuming your matrices are of type `float` -- if you can select int, gcc can auto-vectorise this as well (relates to NaN handling); furthermore `int16_t` or `int8_t` types are even quicker to evaluate, as more operations can be packed to a single SIMD instruction.